# Diodes block voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, diodes

I understand the basics of a diode, a diode allows current to flow in only one direction, but how? By blocking any opposing voltages source so that no current can flow in opposition?

And of course, a diode has its limit. If there is a voltage in opposition that is higher to what the diode can handle it allows current to flow in opposition.
What about the current that is allowed to flow through the diode is it reduced? For example: Current is supplied by a power supply it flows through a diode in forward direction, if the current was 10A before passing the diode will it still be 10A throughout the diode? If the opposing voltage existed does it reduce that 10A?

And how can I relate the forward bias to this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_region

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What about the current that is allowed to flow through the diode is it
> reduced? For example: Current is supplied by a power supply it flows
> through a diode in forward direction, if the current was 10A before
> passing the diode will it still be 10A throughout the diode? If the
> opposing voltage existed does it reduce that 10A?

It really isn't clear what you're asking but really, all you have to do is to look at the IV curve for a diode.

What is an IV curve?  It gives you the current *through* the diode versus the voltage *across* the diode.  Qualitatively, it looks like this:

[image]

Now remember, *either* the voltage across the diode is positive or negative.  If the voltage is positive, there is *forward* current through the diode.

If the voltage is negative, there is a small *reverse* current until the breakdown voltage and then there is a large reverse breakdown current.

That's really all there is to it.  If there is a 10A forward current through, there is a certain positive (forward) voltage across *period*.

> a diode allows current to flow in only one direction, but how?

There is an enormous amount of material, from the beginner to advance level, on the web describing the operation of the PN junction.  What *specifically* do you not understand?  Your question, as is, is too broad.  Study the operation of the PN junction and then, if it isn't quite clear, ask a specific question.

Comment: In terms of losses I guess the 0.7V drop is that, I assumed some losses across a diode, and I guess the 10A would be somewhat reduced across by a small value.

Comment: @Key, if there is 10A entering the diode, there is 10A leaving the diode and there is 10A through the diode.

Comment: What about voltage drop across the diode? Applied-0.7V(depending on diode type)?

Comment: @Key, your reasoning isn't clear to me.  Try using the schematic editor to draw the circuit you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

There is a wonderful article on PN junctions (which diodes are) in this article titled "How transistors REALLY work": http://amasci.com/amateur/trshort.html

If you're asking how a diode blocks current physically, you should definitely have a look at that.

Objectively, it might not be in the most modern and organised way, but the content is amazingly sound, the best I've seen so far. The longer article (there is a link in that short article) has diagrams.